# What does System.Reflection.Missing.Value do?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I encountered a code given below

```
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
oDataDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(ref oName, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing);
```

I dont understand what will ref oMissing do. Will it automatically get the values or something like that?

Comment: Wow, what the heck, why this value is passed by reference?

Comment: @SargeBorsch who knows? I guess this is some `COM` stuff, and `COM` stuff is always not very readable.

Comment: Yeaah i totally agree with you.

Comment: The example code in this Microsoft article passes a `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` value by reference: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/301659?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It represents `null` value. Note that `null` is not equal to `Missing.Value`

Just to add more information, as you can see in the screen shot below, `Missing.Value` is NOT equal to `null`, and in fact is a new instance of `Missing` class object

[image]

Comment: then what is equal to Missing.Value

Comment: If you pass this value, then the Word API would treat that no value is supplied for the respective parameter. In VB.NET you could avoid sending values that you are not interested in; but earlier C# doesn't used to support default parameters. Hence as an alternative _Missing.Value_ is being used. Unlike null, Missing.Value allows the API to take the default value of that parameter (as defined in it's class) and continue processing.

Answer (score 3):

It represents the `null` value.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.missing.value.aspx)

> Represents the sole instance of the Missing class.

Comment: Why cant we pass null instead of using Missing.Value
I dont understand the logic behind it

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi I guess if the value is null, the behavior may be different from the `Missing.Value`.

Comment: If you pass the value as null then no value is supplied for the parameters. Also check this forum:- http://forums.asp.net/t/1636505.aspx/1